# jQuery-Append method create only element but not the id in the element

Tags: jquery, html

SOLVED:Problem was that i wanted to clear my browser's cache,and maybe the jquery-min map 404 error that i also solved(thank's to undefined help).

I have an html code where i have some div tags:

```
    <div class="results">
        <div id="r1" class="horizontal element">
            <img src="logo1.jpg" class="photo">
            <div id="1" class="data"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And i have this jQuery code where i append more elements to the `<div class="results"></div>` when i click a button:

```
$("#show_more").click(function(){
$(".results").append('<div id="r2" class="horizontal element"><img src="logo2.jpg" class="photo"><div id="2" class="data"></div></div>');});
```

The problem is that if i want to alert() the id of class="data" only the id="1" will show not the id="2" although the element was created(visible).
I have tried to re-arange the position of the jquery code but nothing happens.What am i doing wrong?Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have used `$('.data').attr('id')` for getting the `id`s, `attr` as getter returns value of the first element in the collection, you should iterate through the collection and read the `id`s individually.

> i used `$('.data').click(function(){ alert($(this).attr('id')); });`

This means that you should delegate the event, when the code is executed, `$('.data')` selects the `.data` elements that exist at that specific moment, the collection doesn't contain the generated elements:

```
$('.results').on('click', '.data', function() {
     alert(this.id);
});
```

Also note that you shouldn't use duplicate ids. Your code should handle that.

Comment: Still not working.I get alert message only for the first element that existed.The one that i create with append doesn't even show an alert() box.

Comment: @garrytowel Do you generate the `.results` element dynamically? Which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: No .results exists.I append elements inside it. jQuery v1.10.2

Comment: @garrytowel Well, in that case the above code should work, do you see any errors in the console? Have you put the code in document ready handler? If no, try using `document` object instead of the `'.results'` selector, i.e. `$(document).on...`

Comment: I have an error on the console actualy.
GET http://localhost/series/Site/js/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.map 404 (Not Found).In that folder the only thing i have is the jquery.js which i use...

Comment: @garrytowel That's not really an error, that an `404` error for the `map` file which doesn't matter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61013/discussion-between-garry-towel-and-undefined).